# Fetch SQL data from same table of different column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using get request to fetch `serial` and put it into query.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE serial='.$id.'");
$select->execute();
while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo '
<tr>
    <td>'.$row->pname.'</td>
   <td>'.$row->pcategory.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->serial.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->sku.'</td>
    ';
}
```

My table look like this, I tried using inner join for same table but it didn't work.
When user key in `serial` through get request `localhost?id=12345678` . I want it to show `item1` - `item3`, that match with its `SKU`

```
id | sku | serial   | product_name
0  | ABC | 12345678 | item1
1  | ABC | 87654321 | item2
2  | ABC | 23456789 | item3
3  | DEF | 56789234 | item4
```

Comment: add more details

Comment: And where is this `SKU` coming from? At the moment you are searching for serial in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: ok, i've updated what will happen when user put serial. if serial inputted, it should show others item that have same sku too

Comment: sku is already within the table

Comment: i'm not sure which join to use

Comment: So you want to search for `serial`, get the `SKU` from that serial and then select all the serials with that SKU?

Answer (score 0):

You can try inner join like this:

```
select id, c.sku, serial, product_name from table_name t
inner join (
select sku from table_name where serial ='12345678'
)c on t.sku = c.sku
```

in your code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "select id, c.sku, serial, product_name from table_name t
inner join (
select sku from table_name where serial = :serial
)c on t.sku = c.sku";
$select = $pdo->prepare($query);
$select->bindParam(':serial', $id);
$select->execute();
while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo '
<tr>
    <td>'.$row->pname.'</td>
   <td>'.$row->pcategory.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->serial.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->sku.'</td>
    ';
}
```

Don't trust any input, use `prepare`, and `bindParam` to avoid SQL injection. You can reference SQL injection here https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select * from tbl_product where sku = (select sku from tbl_product where serial = :serial)
```

might do it, presuming a PDO prepared statement.

Answer (score -1):

**Self join**

```
$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product P1 LEFT JOIN tbl_product P2 ON P2.sku = P1.sku  WHERE P1.serial='.$id.'")
```